# Google Charts not showing in IE 8

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

Hi I've got a basic chart that isn't showing in IE 8 or 9.  Works in IE 10.  The space is just blank.  Here's the code:

```
   var colors = ['#C02942', '#53777A', '#ECD078', '#542437', '#D95B43'];

   var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([['Month', 'Clicked','Delivered','Sent'],['12/11', 0,0,0],['1/12', 1,1,1],['2/12', 0,0,1],['3/12', 0,0,0],['4/12', 0,0,0],['5/12', 0,0,1],['6/12', 0,0,2],['7/12', 0,0,0],['8/12', 0,0,2],['9/12', 0,0,0],['10/12', 0,0,0],['11/12', 0,0,0],['12/12', 0,0,0],['1/13', 0,0,0],['2/13', 0,0,0],['3/13', 0,0,1],['4/13', 0,0,0],['5/13', 0,0,3],['6/13', 0,0,0]]);


   var  options = {
        width: 650,
        colors: colors,
        chartArea: { left: 50, top: 20},
        hAxis: {showTextEvery: 2},
        isStacked: true
    };

 chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
 chart.draw(data, options);
```

TIA

Answer (score 2):

I ran your code in IE9, and it's throwing an error in the JavaScript console (hit F12 to bring the console up). The error is 'colors not defined'. Unless you've defined colors someplace else, that's the error I'm seeing.

Comment: Thanks, yea colors was defined previously in the code.  See edit.

Comment: The code, as posted, has an extra back tick before the 4/13 date. Intentional?

Comment: Was fighting w/ the SO editor.  That character is what denotes the code block and an extra one was added.  has been removed.

Comment: As posted, the code runs without errors in a JSFiddle on IE9, and displays a chart. I haven't compared the chart to other platforms. Is the JSConsole showing any errors?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem was with my google.setOnLoadCallback line.  Since the script was loaded from an ajax call it was not firing in IE 8, just every other browser.  The answer was to just call the 'drawChart' function directly, instead of wrapping it in the google.setOnLoadCallback.

Comment: You don't want to skip the calling google.setOnLoadCallback, as you can end up trying to draw the chart before the API loads that way.  If you stick the AJAX call inside the google loader's callback, that should solve the problem safely.